# How to deal with spillage when my 6-year-old son uses the toilet?

Tags: primary-schooler, development, potty-training

My son is 6 years old. I have been dealing with spillage in the toilet. He himself is very concerned and tries to avoid it by holding his 'thing' and pointing it down. This way he is successful but I am concerned about potential side effects to this practice.

Make note that I have always trained him to pee sitting *not* standing, as it is against my values and I also think it is difficult when you want to wash yourself afterwards with water...

I have also tried making him sit turned the other way. That also minimised the spill but it wasn't 100%.

Comment: Not sure where you're from, but in the United States there is a bit of a stigma with boys/men sitting to pee as it is perceived to be a feminine practice (which hopefully has diminished since I was a young one). It may be a good idea to train him to stand to mitigate any bullying. Dropping in a cheerio into the toilet makes for a good target so that there isn't any spillage. (Trying not to overstep your values, those are important. Just food for thought.)

Comment: what side effects are you concerned about, I can't think of any so please elaborate.  Also, if time permits please share the source of your values about how boys do this.  I'm just curious, guessing it is a cultural thing I've never heard of before, very interested.

Comment: @LuxClaridgethanks for your feedback. yes i know it is a stigma but we have to learn to deal with the stigma so it is no more a stigma :)

Comment: I usually pee sitting down at home, but I think that's just age + smart phone that influence that. **Frankly though, there are some men's toilets I've experienced that make me glad that standing up at a urinal is an option** If you pee sitting down though,(as a man) you kind of have to point it down, or else it will rest on the toilet seat - Don't forget that in later life, that dangly bit will probably be longer (although can be a health hazard if it's touching the inside of a poorly cleaned toilet bowl)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> He himself is very concerned and tries to avoid it by holding his 'thing' and pointing it down. This way he is successful but i am concerned is there any side 
>   effects of this practice.

There are no problematic side effects to this practice. Don't be overly concerned just because genitals are involved. Be happy, he's found a perfectly good solution to his problem.

Comment: Just be sure to wash hands afterwards as there is likely hand contact with the commode. Agreed, this practice is okay and sometimes necessary even in adulthood.

Comment: After re-reading the question - I think he is pointing it downwards when sitting in the proper position. I've done this all my life when doing a number 1&2 as you have to when you grow a bit bigger (body and dangly bits) and sit on the toilet. It's a fact of the male anatomy that you have to point it down into the bowl otherwise it will just rest on the seat pointing to the floor. So, agree with the above - there's no side effect to this I can think of